# Macbook Pro 8,2 Graphics switching - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, uefi, hybrid-graphics, refit, macbook-pro

I've been reading docs and various pages for a few hours now and can't seem to put all of the pieces together on this. Basically I am trying to get 12.04 installed on my MBP 8,2 with graphics card switching working in some way or another. My basic understanding is that I need to do an EFI boot install of ubuntu so that graphics card switching will work (due to the hardware design). From there I may be able to use one of the kernel modules for graphics switching:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

That article isn't clear on whether I need to do an EFI install. I have also seen comments in posts here that say and EFI install works by default as long as you have refit installed. Overall, I'm quite lost as to the simplest way to proceed to get an install up and running with graphics switching. I don't mind using open source GFX drivers as long as the basics work.

Any help towards a solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help on the graphics card switching, but I've got a Web page that details one way of installing Ubuntu in EFI mode on Macs:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html

The procedure is much too long to describe fully here, but in brief, it involves doing a BIOS-mode install and then booting and ripping out the BIOS-mode stuff and replacing it with EFI-mode stuff. There may well be other ways to do this, and the optimal methods may well vary from one model to another, so this is very much a "use at your own risk" sort of proposition, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your mac in EFI mode for the switching to work properly. And there is no need to be ripping the bios stuff.

I'm successfully using hybrid graphics on my Macbook Pro 8.2. 
This howto should be enough to allow you to switch between gfx cards
[How to switch between Gfx cards on Macbook Pro 15" 8.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184406/how-to-switch-between-gfx-cards-on-macbook-pro-15-8-2)