# How to switch between Gfx cards on Macbook Pro 15" 8.2

Tags: radeon, macbook-pro, vgaswitcheroo, grub-efi

I have a Macbook  15" Pro 8.2

Which apparently is supposed to be switchable between the GFX cards with vgaswitcheroo.
But /sys/kernel/debug/ contains no switcheroo folder.

syslog gives me this.

```
[   21.631041] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[   21.631075] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents
[   21.631149] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents
[   21.631154] [drm:radeon_get_bios] *ERROR* Unable to locate a BIOS ROM
[   21.631163] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Fatal error during GPU init
[   21.631165] [drm] radeon: finishing device.
[   21.631166] [TTM] Memory type 2 has not been initialized
[   21.632193] radeon 0000:01:00.0: no bo for sa manager
[   21.632197] vga_switcheroo: disabled
```

it seems that it tries to enable it but then fails.
In other faqs on the net i hear that when booting in efi mode there is no bios. And because of this the ati card cant initialize properly. Sounds like it could be the reason. Anyone know how to load the bios rom when in efi mode?

--ok some updates--
There is a  patch that works. Allowing the loading of the video bios from a file for the 3.4 kernel.

These features have been merged into 3.6-rc 3 apparently. But I'm on that kernel and still cant switch over to the ATI card.

apparently [others](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26891) have the same issue

Comment: Did you mean `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/`?

Comment: yup, edited the question

Comment: You write that you have a 13" Macbook Pro 8.1, but that has only integrated graphics. So you either have a MBP 8.2 or 8.3.

Comment: Yup its a 8.2. changed the number.

Comment: commenting on your answer is closed, so I gotta ask here: - Your point is using Kernel 3.8, so Ubuntu Raring should do - `/dev/sda6` is your Ubuntu root partition? - This should be compatible with Ubuntu Kernel updates, when `ESP/EFI/ubuntu/` is mounted to `/boot` (usual place of vmlinuz and initrd), right?

Comment: updated my answer to clarify your questions a bit

Comment: - Which drivers do you use?
- Have you ever tried to connect to an external display and run your MacBook with two screens? In my case either the MacBook's LCD or the external Display remains black. I am currently using the Open Source X-Org drivers (default in 13.04?). Yesterday I tried to install the AMD/ATI 13.4 driver, but eventually I failed. Is there a nice howto somewhere on how to install these drivers properly? Or aren't these drivers necessary to get vga-switcheroo running?

Comment: I'm using the native open souce radeon driver. Using a secondary external display along side the laptop display works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it. I can successfully use the ATI card and also use an external display for dual head.

1. Have ubuntu installed and running in efi mode using the native builtin default radeon driver
2. Install the 3.8 ubuntu kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-rc2-raring/):
3. Install the [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) (refit replacement boot manager for efi macs
4. copy vmlinuz-3.8.0-030800rc2-generic and
   initrd.img-3.8.0-030800rc2-generic to /boot/efi/ubuntu/
5. create a the file /boot/efi/ubuntu/refind_linux.conf enter this into
   it: "Boot with sda6"         "root=/dev/sda6 add_efi_memmap
   modprobe.blacklist=i915 radeon.modeset=1 elevator=noop vt.handoff=7 
   ro

this will give you a new option to boot the 3.8 kernel directly from the refit menu entierly bypassing grub which is needed for the switching to work properly.

6) The actual switch needs to be done from console, with GDM stopped. It also seems to  works best if its done after a fresh start of the machine.
7) echo DIGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch , as root to switch to the Intel card
8)echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch, as root to switch to the ati card

For me every other release candidate strangely enough seem to have broken USB support . If your keyboard doesn't work, try another latest working for me is 3.8 rc6.

the /boot/efi  is where my efi paritition gets mounted in Linux. The efi partition is where you need to put the files for efi(refind) to detect your kernel and initrd.
if you cannot see it. Check gparted for it. It has a fat32 filesystem and should have the label EFI.

Comment: Using this instruction with the native kernel in 13.04. works fine