# How To Use Intel Graphics on MacBook Pro w/12.10?

Tags: 12.10, intel-graphics, radeon, macbook-pro, i915

I've installed 12.10 on a MacBook Pro 8,2 using the Mac install image. The install was successful, but I don't see the /boot/efi partition I expected to see. Therefore, I assume it was not an EFI install.  There is a boot_grub partition, instead.

More to the point of this question, lspci sees only the AMD card, not that and the integrated Intel GPU.  Being able to use vgaswitcheroo to enable the Intel card was the primary motivation for installing 12.10. Vgaswitcheroo isn't in /sys/kernel/debug, though.

The fglrx drivers from Additional Drivers result in a broken display:  No Dash and no panel.  I've no option but to use the default open source Radeon driver and that seems to trigger the fans quite often.

So, I'd like to use the Intel card in the hope it won't push the fans as much.

How can I get from here to there?

Comment: Would help us if we knew which MacBook model you have. I.E. It's release year / version. Once you know please edit your question and the community might be able to help you quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing  with the ordinary PC Install image would have given you an EFI install right away.

First install [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)

then to fix your current situation:

**Option one:**
Try installing grub-efi from the package manager(It should replace your ordinary grub) . Don't know about the EF partition. I guess you could use gparted resize a part of your disk to make space for a small vfat partition to keep your EFI stuff on.

**Option two:** 
reinstall from scratch booting the Ubuntu installer through the EFI mode it provides.

**Option three**:
boot the Linux kernel directly from refind bypassing grub entirely. This is the only option that give you the capabilities to use switcheroo to switch between your graphics cards. You should be able to deduce the steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184406/how-to-switch-between-gfx-cards-on-macbook-pro-15-8-2/240428#240428)

I prefer option three. Since it gives the most flexibility.